# Moving a PostgreSQL database from Windows to CentOS with different collations

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, centos

We have a production server on windows with a PostgreSQL database described as:

```
LC_COLLATE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'
LC_CTYPE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'
```

The thing is, when we work on our development machines, which are all CentOS, the PostgreSQL installation only allow us to create databases on this format:

```
LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8'
```

or

```
LC_COLLATE = 'pt_BR.UTF8'
LC_CTYPE = 'pt_BR.UTF8'
```

This is affecting the way we store dates and timestamps on each one of them.
How can i replicate the collation of the windows database on the centOS machine? The other way around can be a solution too.

Comment: Dates and timestamps aren't stored with a specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the date format in postgresql.conf:

```
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
```

Adjust the `mdy` part. Look at [Locale and Formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT)

How are the dates entered? If the date input format starts with a four digits year it is unambiguous:

```
'2013-03-14 10:19'
```

Try to use that format everywhere. Check the [date input format details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)

As commented by @a_horse the date stored format is always the same, a binary. What you can configure is the input and output format.

Comment: The timestamps are being entered in the format: `dd/mm/YYYY H:M:S`. The thing is, in the windows database it saves correctly, but on centOS databases it show an out of range error, possibly due to the date format.

Comment: @MurifoX Then use `datestyle = 'iso, dmy'` in the CentOS server.

Comment: You could as I'm in Brasília but I don't like _cerveja goiana_ as it always come with those _sertanejo_ songs :)))